# How to override a function in derived class when Inheriting

Tags: c++

I have two classes - Mother(Base) and Daughter(Derived). I am inheriting a function from Mother class and trying to override in Daughter class. It looks like that it overrides, but my confusion is, even though I don't inherit Mother class, the function still works, so how am I inheriting/overriding it? I am very confused as if I'm really inheriting/overriding anything. Please note in the Derived class that I am not inheriting `: public Mother`
Thanks for the help, as always!!!

This is my code

Mother.hpp

```
#ifndef Mother_hpp
#define Mother_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Mother
{
public:
    Mother();

    void sayName();

    };
```

Mother.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Mother.hpp"
#include "Daughter.hpp"
using namespace std;

Mother::Mother(){}

void Mother::sayName(){
    cout<<"I am Sandy" <<endl;
}
```

Daughter.hpp

```
#ifndef Daughter_hpp
#define Daughter_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Mother.hpp"

class Daughter : public Mother
{
public:
    Daughter();

    void sayName();
};
```

Daughter.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mother.hpp"
#include "Daughter.hpp"
using namespace std;

Daughter::Daughter() : Mother(){}

void Daughter::sayName(){
    cout << "my name is sarah" <<endl;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mother.hpp"
#include "Daughter.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Mother mom;
    mom.sayName();

    Daughter d;
    d.sayName();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of running your code?

Comment: I am Sandy
my name is sarah
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: So... they each have a function called `sayName()` and each function is being called... this has nothing to do with overriding, inheritance, or anything like that.

Comment: was -1 really necessary? :(

Comment: Usually this wouldn't be an issue, you would probably have a super class or base class that would have sayName as a pure virtual function like this:    virtual void sayName() = 0; Or just have each class inside a name space!

Comment: I would say this is a decent question, I will make it + 1.

Comment: Thank You @OmidCompSCI for your answer and encouragement!!!

Comment: Reasons for downvote: 1) Not providing output of the code in the question itself (you're printing messages for the purposes of debugging, you really ought to provide that info to people answer the question).  2) You pose it as a question of inheritance, you **say** you're inheriting, and then you actually don't inherit anything and you even **say** you aren't inheriting, which pretty much makes the question at the very least ill-considered.

Comment: Thank You @tmpearce for your answer. I'll definitely keep these notes handy! :)

Comment: You're calling `Mother` a base class and `Daughter` a derived class, but since you're not actually inheriting (extending) the "Base" class, there is actually no relationship at all between these classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but my confusion is, even though I don't inherit Mother class, the function still works, so how am I inheriting/overriding it? I am very confused as if I'm really inheriting/overriding anything.

- you don't really override sayName() of your Mother class because (as you said) Daughter class doesn't inherit it in the first place. That is, you need to inherit a class first in order to be able to **override** its **virtual** functions.
- your second call to sayName() works because it's a call to a member function of Daughter class, which is totally independent from Mother class. Note that, just having multiple independent classes whose member functions share the same signature is not **overriding**
- side note:  you shouldn't include Daughter.hpp in Mother.cpp, whether you plan to inherit Mother in Daughter, or not.